# Node JS- Express Module /Sessions and Passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to make a simple express-server with Node JS using sessions and passport authentication. So, i've made the /users/login,/users/signup routes  and the sticking point is the /users/logout route.  When i make a post request with the credentials in JSON format using postman everything goes well and  a cookie is made   as it should be. When i am trying to logout, the cookie is deleted. After this,  i make again a logout request. The the expected message is "Sorry you are not logged in" . But the message " Successfully logged out!" appears again and again.
Any help ?

Sorry for my english.

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
  User.register(new User({username: req.body.username, email:req.body.email, phone:req.body.phone, userType:req.body.userType}), 
    req.body.password, (err, user) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err)
      res.statusCode = 500;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.json({err: err});
    }
    else {
      passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, () => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json({success: true, status: 'Registration Successful!'});
      });
    }
  });
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
  console.log('Here it is a post login request');
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.json({success: true, status: 'You are successfully logged in!'});
});

router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {

  if (req.session) {
    req.session.destroy();
    res.clearCookie('session-id');
    res.end('Successfully logged out!');
  }
  else {
    var err = new Error('You are not logged in!');
    err.status = 403;
    next(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: print the value of req.session, you will be able to debug it.

Comment: I have printed it and the "path" member has always the string "/" in it.